# DataBinding Updating But View Isn't

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding

I have a property (**FileName**) that is updating just fine when I watch it in the debugger, (while hovering over the property both in the view model and in the XAML), but the UI will not reflect the value updates. I have a breakpoint set on `set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _fileName, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }` and can watch it enter it and raise the change notification via `RaisePropertyChanged()`.

I'm instantiating it to an initial value of "Not Updated" via `FileName = "Not Updated";`, and while the property is successfully updated to other values through the application's run duration via `FileName = SelectRandomString();`, the UI never updates. Relevant UI Code:

```
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.DataContext>
                                <ns:ProgressViewModel />
                            </TextBlock.DataContext>
                        </TextBlock>
```

Full view model:

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MaterialDesignTest
{
    public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer progressTimer;

    private double _saveProgressButton;
    public double SaveProgressButton
    {
        get { return _saveProgressButton; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _saveProgressButton, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _fileName, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaveComplete;
    public bool IsSaveComplete
    {
        get { return _isSaveComplete; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaveComplete, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaving;
    public bool IsSaving
    {
        get { return _isSaving; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaving, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    int progress = 0;
    int cycles = 0;
    public ProgressViewModel()
    {
        FileName = "Not Updated";

    }
    public void KickOffProgressTimer()
    {
        progressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        progressTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(progressTimerTick);
        progressTimer.Interval = 40;
        progressTimer.Start();
    }

    private async void progressTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileName = SelectRandomString();

        if (progress < 100 && cycles < 2)
        {
            if (progress == 99)
            {
                cycles++;
                progress = 0;
            }

            IsSaveComplete = false;
            IsSaving = true;
            progress++;
            SaveProgressButton = progress;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSaveComplete = true;
            IsSaving = false;
            progressTimer.Enabled = false;
            SaveProgressButton = 0;

            await NonBlockingDelay(1750);

            DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand.Execute(null, null);
        }
    }
    async Task NonBlockingDelay(int value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    static string SelectRandomString()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var questions = new List<string>{
            @"C:\Files\Filename1",
            @"C:\Filename2",
            @"C:\Filename3",
            @"C:\Filename4",
            @"C:\Temp\Files\Filename5",
            @"C:\Filename6",
            @"C:\Demo\LongFolderName\Filename7",
            @"C:\Filename8",
            @"C:\Filename9",
        };
        int index = random.Next(questions.Count);
        return(questions[index]);
    }
}

}
```

Code for MutateVerbose:

```
        public static void MutateVerbose<TField>(this INotifyPropertyChanged instance, ref TField field, TField newValue, Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> raise, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
        if (EqualityComparer<TField>.Default.Equals(field, newValue)) return;
        field = newValue;
        raise?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

**Update**: If I kickoff the progress timer as part of the view model loading like so:

```
        public ProgressViewModel()
        {
        KickOffProgressTimer();
        }
```

The UI is updated as it should be. But I don't understand this behavior and it's not desirable. I don't want the `KickOffProgressTimer();` method to be executing as soon as the app starts, rather only when a button is clicked from the mainwindow code behind:

```
        private void CircleButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           ProgressViewModel pvm = new ProgressViewModel();
           CircleButton.DataContext = pvm;
           pvm.KickOffProgressTimer();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for MutateVerbose.  It's up to you of course but are you sure you want to use the WinForms timer?

Comment: Added the code for MutateVerbose to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `UpdateSourceTrigger` event that will trigger UI update:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way you're raising the property changed event. Have you tried using the new `PropertyChanged` implementation which was added for `C# 6.0`. I stripped down your code to the following and it works fine.

```
public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set
        {
            _fileName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ProgressViewModel()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var timer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 200,
        };

        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => FileName = random.Next().ToString();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an update to the question since it is now working, but I'm not sure why (and how it's working isn't desirable).

Comment: @user3342256 don't you need to add the name of the property when you call `RaisePropertyChanged` without the `C# 6.0` syntax e.g. `RaisePropertyChanged("FileName")`